# PHP Link to session_destroy

Tags: hyperlink, php

I need to make a link that when clicked will run this in php:

```
session_destroy();
```

I know how to make a link in html, but I don't know how to make it interact with php. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ehm http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22session_destroy%22

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For an example, you want to use this script for logging out.

Your HTML has to be something like this for "index.php" (just an example)

```
<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

Then on the "logout.php"

```
session_start(); //to ensure you are using same session
session_destroy(); //destroy the session
header("location:index.php"); //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
exit();
```

In case you want to use JavaScript, I can tell you that too?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't need JavaScript but thanks for the offer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// logout.php
session_destroy();
```

Then make a link to `logout.php`

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is call a PHP script, which calls that function.

Comment: So just create a link to a php scrip in html?