# HTML- and PHP-code inside an PHP 'if statement'

Tags: php, html, if-statement

What if I want to have HTML code inside my 'if' statement, and then php code in the 'else' part? What do I do? I have tried this, but with no luck..

```html
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['bnavn']) : ?>

   'HTML-code'

<?php else : ?>

    'PHP-code'
    
<?php endif: ?>
```

I have also tried this, but also with no luck:

```html
<?php

    session_start();

    if ($_SESSION['bnavn']) : ?>

       'HTML-code'

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php 'PHP-code' ?>
        
    <?php endif: ?>
```

Comment: @LukePark yes it does http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Apologies, wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @Troels read that link above, take note of the semi-colon after the endif

Comment: The second way should work (besides the colon at the end that should be a semi-colon). What is the problem? Why not provide the exact code you are trying with?

Comment: An entire page is inside the if statement. This page should only be shown if the statement is true, and if not, it should with PHP-code in the 'else' part 'die' like: <?php die ("You are not logged in!"); ?>

Comment: But despite the fact that I log out, which means the session is destroyed, I am still able to direct to this 'page' referred to before. It should instead output "You are not logged ind!" ..

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out! I found this link: [PHP Session Destroy on Log Out Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001702/php-session-destroy-on-log-out-button)

I made the if statement as one of the answers said, and changed my page.html to page.php. I do not know if it have to .php instead of .html, but not it works!